# @AutoValue is not working on Intellij 2016.1.3

Tags: java, intellij-idea, auto-value

I was try to use Google's @AutoValue.
But, It's not working on my Intellij.

**Step.1** I was maked this class

```
import com.google.auto.value.AutoValue;

@AutoValue
public abstract class Example {
  public static Example create(String name, int integer) {
    return new AutoValue_Example(name, integer);
  }

  public abstract String name();
  public abstract int integer();
}
```

then

**Step.2** typed this code into the build.gradle

```
dependencies {
    testCompile group: 'junit', name: 'junit', version: '4.11'
    compile group: 'com.google.auto.value', name: 'auto-value', version: '1.2'
}
```

**Step.3** I had install AutoValue Plugin.

but Java complier give this error to me:

```
Error:(12, 20) java: cannot find symbol
  symbol:   class AutoValue_Animal
  location: class Animal
```

Comment: And the target sub-directory where the autovalue classes are generated into is marked as "Source", right?

Comment: Your IDE needs to be set up to process annotations. Take a look at [this](https://github.com/google/auto/issues/106#issuecomment-44096827) and [this](http://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/2016.1/configuring-annotation-processing.html).

Comment: It's works!. thank you for your answer.

Comment: In my case the code just isn't generated.  Despite activating the annotation processors. :-(